# Objects Unable to be read twice with ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, file, data-structures, file-io

Whenever I write the the file the initial time everything is fine. When I read the data into the linked list everything is fine. Then finally when I save the file the files contents match with the initial file where I just wrote it.

The issue I have is when I try to read the objects from the saved file (after running the program for the second time) is that everything in the file is erased and I can't read any objects in.

```
public class MedicalInformation {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, EOFException {


        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the file path");
        String filePath = userInput.next(); //"C:\\Users\\ag\\Desktop\\medicalData\\patient.dat";
        System.out.println("The file's path is " + filePath);
        System.out.println("Enter the file name and its path you want to read in");

        // create objects that allow one to read and write to the file
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));

        //creates the objects to be written into the file

        Patient p1 = new Patient("Alex", "1123 metropolitan Queens NY 11385", new Date("11/20/1997"));
        p1.setFirstVisit(new Date("11/20/1997"));
        p1.setHeight(72);
        p1.setLastVisit(new Date("11/20/1997"));
        p1.setWeight(200);
        out.writeObject(p1);
        System.out.println(p1);

        Patient p2 = new Patient("John", "200 avenue of americas Manhttann 10111", new Date("12/20/1999"));
        p2.setFirstVisit(new Date("11/11/2005"));
        p2.setHeight(5);
        p2.setLastVisit(new Date("11/21/2010"));
        p2.setWeight(150);
        out.writeObject(p2);

        Patient p3 = new Patient("Sarah", "24 Park avenue Manhttann 10111", new Date("09/07/1960"));
        p3.setFirstVisit(new Date("05/11/1977"));
        p3.setHeight(75);
        p3.setLastVisit(new Date("01/21/2017"));
        p3.setWeight(110);
        out.writeObject(p3);

        Patient p4 = new Patient("Malcolm", "56street East NY 10444", new Date("05/28/1977"));
        p4.setFirstVisit(new Date("01/11/1990"));
        p4.setHeight(75);
        p4.setLastVisit(new Date("8/21/2016"));
        p4.setWeight(155);
        out.writeObject(p4);

        Patient p5 = new Patient("Johnny", "89 street Jamaica 12221", new Date("12/25/1944"));
        p5.setFirstVisit(new Date("03/16/1966"));
        p5.setHeight(55);
        p5.setLastVisit(new Date("5/21/2015"));
        p5.setWeight(355);
        out.writeObject(p5);

        Patient p6 = new Patient("Laura", "east 4th street Brooklyn 12214", new Date("08/08/1988"));
        p6.setFirstVisit(new Date("05/11/1999"));
        p6.setHeight(48);
        p6.setLastVisit(new Date("8/21/2012"));
        p6.setWeight(350);
        out.writeObject(p6);



        //put them into a list
        List < Patient > list = new List < Patient > ();


        boolean done = false;
        while (!done) {
            try {
                Patient patients = (Patient) in .readObject();
                list.add(patients);
                //an EOFException is thrown when the stream ends, which means the end of the file is reached
            } catch (EOFException e) {
                done = true;
                out.close(); in .close();
            }
        }




        if (option == 8) {
            System.out.println("Would you like to save the file y/n");
            saveFile = userInput.next();

            if (saveFile.equals("y")) {
                //save file
                System.out.println("Enter the file's name where it is to be saved");
                filePath = userInput.next();
                out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
                LLNode < Patient > p = list.getList();
                while (p != null) {
                    out.writeUnshared(p.getInfo());
                    p = p.getLink();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("You chose not to save the file");
            }
            out.close(); in .close();
            break;
        }
    }

}
}
```

So What I do is I enter the file name C:\Users\ag\Desktop\medicalData\patient.dat
then the six objects get written to it.

I then read these into the linked list

I perform no operations

I save the linked list to a file C:\Users\ag\Desktop\medicalData\patient.dat

I comment out writing the 6 objects into the file now I just want to read them. This is where my problem is I end up left with a file with two characters and am unable get an EOFException.

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve] and format the code appropriately. Very little of the code you've shown is really relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Serializing the same object will deserialize the same object, even if you changed it at the sending end. You need to use one of:

- `ObjectOutputStream.reset()`
- `ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared()`
- `ObjectInputStream.readUnshared()`.